# Microsoft Edge is not reusing a child tab as of 6/26/2022

Tags: javascript, tabs, microsoft-edge

Before this weekend we were using the following code in Microsoft Edge to open or reuse a tab from the parent to child tab so as to not be over loaded with tabs.
`function launchProfile(profileLink){`
`profileLink += 'profile=' + tempProfile + '&profileNumber=' + tempProfileNumber;`
`window.open(profileLink,'profileTab');`
`}`

As a user looks at different profiles they click a button to view an outside website, passing profile parameters to load the page. Before this weekend this was functioning as expected with only one child tab being created and used. As of today each time the button is clicked a new tab is created. Is there either a setting in Edge or Windows that would control that behavior?

Comment: Well just found out that site being accessed had removed the policy for the URL to open in IE11 mode and instead use native Edge. That still doesn't explain why ```window.open()``` as I'm using it won't reuse the child tab.

Comment: It looks like the update of Edge version 103 caused the issue, but I can't be sure. If possible, can you test it to determine the cause of the problem. Just refer to [this policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-update-policies#rollbacktotargetversion) to rollback the version of Edge.